# Unable to figure out what syntax error I have in my for-loop

Tags: for-loop, syntax-error

```
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,50)
        for i in range(len(creditcard_df.columns)):
          plt.subplot(17,1,i+1) #to plot 17,1,1 17,1,2 17,1,3 etc. 
          sns.distplot(creditcard_df[creditcard_df.columns[i]],kde_kws= 
          {"color":"b","lw":2,"label":"KDE"},hist_kws={"color":"g")
          plt.title(creditcard_df.columns[i]) #the index titles seen above

        plt.tight_layout
```

The error message is as follows:

File "", line 5
for i in range(len(creditcard_df.columns)):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks in advance, appreciate any advice you guys can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually on the first line where you forgot to close a bracket.
`plt.figure(figsize=(10,50))`